# Insert into an unordered_set failed

Tags: c++

First of all, this is **NOT** my own code! It's taken from Google's Android sourcecode https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/android-9.0.0_r10/tools/hiddenapi/hiddenapi.cc
So, it **should** be tested and **should** work! But, it fails at the point "insert..."
Short code:

```
/*...*/
std::unordered_set<std::string> light_greylist_;
/*...*/

/*Caller:*/ OpenApiFile(light_greylist_path_, &light_greylist_);

bool OpenApiFile(const std::string& path, std::unordered_set<std::string>* list) {

  std::ifstream api_file(path, std::ifstream::in);

  for (std::string line; std::getline(api_file, line);) {
/* line IS filled; I've checked it with a simple fprintf(): [this IS my code for testing]*/
    FILE *stream = fopen("test.txt", "a+");
    fprintf(stream, "%s\n", line.c_str());
    fclose(stream);

/* This is the point where it crashes with an "Illegal instruction (core dumped)"*/
    list->insert(line);
  }

  api_file.close();
  return true;
}
```

What goes wrong?

Comment: can you provide a [mcve]? Passing an invalid pointer may cause the issue, so it depends on what you have in place of `/*...*/`

Comment: Illegal instruction could be caused by jumping to a bad address, but also by compiling for a slightly different CPU than the code ends up running on. So it would be useful to know: what the illegal instruction is (totally invalid vs merely not supported by your CPU), what CPU you're using, what CPU you compiled for

Comment: The whole code can be found at the given address in my post.

Comment: The CPU is an AMD 64bit Phenom. I tried to compile and run the code also on an other AMD 64bit Athlon. The code has to be performed only on one CPU and has no effect later on the android device.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make `list` a reference instead of a pointer. It's hard to say why the original code uses pointers since it'll most probably crash if called with NULL. Also check that the file has been successfully opened (even though it seems to have succeeded for you this time).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>

bool OpenApiFile(const std::string& path, std::unordered_set<std::string>& list) {

  std::ifstream api_file(path, std::ifstream::in);
  if (!api_file) {
    return false;
  }

  for (std::string line; std::getline(api_file, line);) {
    list.insert(line);
  }

  return true;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::vector<std::string> files(argv+1, argv+argc);

  for(auto& light_greylist_path_ : files) {
    std::unordered_set<std::string> light_greylist_;

    if (OpenApiFile(light_greylist_path_, light_greylist_) == false) {
      std::cerr << "failed opening "+light_greylist_path_+"\n";
    } else {
      for(auto& lg : light_greylist_) {
        std::cout << lg << "\n";
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The file has been successfully opened! When commenting the insert-line (//), I can print a lot of successfully read lines.
The idea for using a pointer seems to be that they want to modify the values in light_greylist_ directly. (It's a guess)

Comment: @Bernhard light_greylist_ is modified directly in this version too. Making it a reference instead of a pointer makes it less likely that you supply something invalid to the function.

Comment: I've added a main() function so you can test it. You can supply the same file(s) at the command line to this program that you try opening in your program and see if you get the same problems.

Comment: Weird! That's working! So, the problem must be in the build environment of the android source code, because EVERY try of manipulating these unordered_set's (pointer or reference) causes an immediate crash!
[Please excuse my english]

Comment: You are not changing the strings after you've stored them in the set, are you?

Comment: No. But I don't know exactly what the program is for. It's called hiddenapi. It's usage can be read here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/android-9.0.0_r10/tools/hiddenapi/README.md
In fact, every insert() or emplace() made on the unordered_set causes a crash! So, it's not possible to store something in the set.
I've seen that google is using clang instead of g++. Maybe there is the problem... ???

Comment: If you are linking your g++ compiled object files with clang++ compiled object files/libs, you can _perhaps_ stumble on some ABI incompatibility, but if you compile everything with g++, inserting into unordered_sets should work fine. I've used them with g++ many times.

Comment: Yes; your test example works fine with g++, but in android development, clang is the only allowed compiler!

Comment: I see. I got confused since you mentioned g++. Are you using a supported toolchain to compile hiddenapi.cc and all its dependencies?

Comment: I can't compile hiddenapi.cc itself. It's part of a longer running complex building system.
My idea is to copy the source and all dependencies to my standard linux pc and compile it with g++, copy the executable back to the android development pc, change the calling of the executable and see if that's working...
BTW: There is a second source file with similiar problems... Maybe this will take more time... ;-)

Comment: The mentioned idea is not working! It seems not to be possible to compile one of these sources separately.
So, I'm sorry, but I have to give up... :-(

Comment: Why not do the changes on the development pc directly? Is your development pc also running linux? Why not use clang++ on  the linux pc too?

Comment: Both are running linux, yes! The problem on the development pc is the very long running compile job. That takes over one hour...
That's the reason why I'm copying the source and all dependencies to my linux pc and try it there.
g++ gives a huge number of errors; clang only four. Don't know why...
All errors are like: "error: no member named 'search' in namespace 'std' "
I have to search why this happens...

Comment: That particular error is probably caused by a missing include (<algorithm>).
Have you reconfigured the project(s) after you copied the source code? Many projects need to investigate the environment (via ./configure or something similar) to be able to create the proper setup for 'make' (or whatever is used to build). Please add the exact errors you get to the original post or create a new topic since the problem now has shifted to a compilation error rather than a run-time crash.

Comment: The main problem still exists: A call insert() crashes the program.
So, I've copied the source-file and all needed header-files to my work pc in one temporary directory. I had to change most of the header-files, because they're using paths to call other header-files.
There is no ./configure or anything like that. That's all done by the long running building process.
In the meanwhile I fixed all error-messages by "g++ -std=gnu++17 hiddenapi.cc > hiddenapi.log  2>&1"
But I still got some errors that I can't fix, because I've never seen this.
I'll create a new topic for this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52893876/errors-while-compiling-a-complex-android-source-code-on-my-linux-pc